CMake not able to compile a simple test program on Debian
I'm trying to compile SDL3 from the Github source on the raspberry OS (Debian), but I cant seem to get it to work. I use this: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/Installation Wiki as an installation guide, but it gives me the Error that it "cant compile a simple test program". Full Error Message:
pi@raspberrypi:~/SDL/build $ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
enter code here-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/pi/SDL/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-zzRlRw

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_426a2 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_426a2.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_426a2
    FAILED: cmTC_426a2
    : && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/cmTC_426a2.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_426a2   && :
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/SDL/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/SDL/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I am running this on a Raspberrypi 5 with 4gb RAM using Debian 12 (bookworm). I tried doing it with Ninja, but it didnt work and I also reinstalled GNU.
I'd appreciate if there is some way to fix this, thank you :).

You don't seem to have a complete compiler or set of development libraries installed.
